# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$$')

Tags: svelte

`I set up TypeScript in Svelte. After building the project, I get this error:

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$$')

There is a Panel component.

```
<script>
    import './styles.scss';
</script>

<div class="s3solution-panel-root">
    <div class="s3solution-panel js-panel-main">
        <div class="s3solution-panel-toggler">
            <div class="s3solution-panel-toggler__btn">
                <div class="js-panel-toggler-text">button</div>
                <i class="s3solution-panel-toggler__arr"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="s3solution-panel-toggler__shadow"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I connect it like this:

```
<script lang="ts">
    import Panel from './components/Panel/Panel.svelte';
</script>
<Panel/>
```

```
import App from './App.svelte';

const app = new App({
    target: document.body,
});

export default app;
```

After building, I get this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '$$')

Comment: That is a runtime error that should not have anything to do with TS. Would recommend adding the full stack trace so it is easier to see where it happens and where it originated.